# Is there an addslashes equivalent in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Using Ruby how would I be able to automatically escape single and double quotes in some of the variables being written to the output file. Coming from PHP I'm looking for an addslashes type function, but there doesn't seem to be a simple solution for this in Ruby.

```
require "csv"

def generate_array( file )
    File.open("#{file}" + "_output.txt", 'w') do |output|
        CSV.foreach(file) do |img, _, part, focus, country, loc, lat, lon, desc, link|
            output.puts("[#{lat}, #{lon}, '#{img.downcase}', '#{part}', '#{loc}', '#{focus}', '#{country}', '#{desc}', '#{link}'],")
        end
    end
end

ARGV.each do |file|
    generate_array(file)
end
```

Comment: The output is plain text, the format is a sort of 2D array style, to be used in a JavaScript program I'm working on.
For example [123.123, 123.123, 'img', 'part', 'loc' ... etc],
of course problems arise when one of the string variables contains a single-quote.

Comment: If the output is supposed to be used in JavaScript, why not save a lot of time and effort and use JSON? JSON is well defined and has extensive library support: you'd just build the right Ruby data structure, call `to_json` on it, and move on to more interesting problems.

Comment: raina77ow, and mu is too short Yeah, that seems to be the way to go about it. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose you can emulate PHP `addslashes` functionality with this Ruby construct:

```
.gsub(/['"\\\x0]/,'\\\\\0')
```

For example:

```
slashed_line = %q{Here's a heavily \s\l\a\s\h\e\d "string"}
puts slashed_line.gsub(/['"\\\x0]/,'\\\\\0')
# Here\'s a heavily \\s\\l\\a\\s\\h\\e\\d \"string\"
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems this would be the answer to my question.

Comment: Well, I've just answered the question asked (because someone probably will look exactly for it). But in your situation I'd probably drop `addslashes` approach altogether - and go for JSON. )

Answer (score 4):

There is also [String#dump](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-dump):

```
slashed_line = %q{Here's a heavily \s\l\a\s\h\e\d "string"}
puts slashed_line.dump
#=> "Here's a heavily \\s\\l\\a\\s\\h\\e\\d \"string\""
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Ruby, but I know that in PHP `addslashes` is pretty much deprecated.

Every time that you need to escape data, it requires a different escape routine.  HTML needs different encoding and handling over database work, and each database has its own special rules.

I assume by your question that you are looking to output things to a CSV file.  That, again, opens up a whole kettle of fish as there is no standard CSV.  You'll need to do some research on both what will be making the data (and if it will be strict ASCII or Unicode or something else) and which format of escaping quotes will be needed.  Most CSV consumers use a two double quotes to replace a single double quote.  If you need `"` in your string, you write `""`.

Comment: Oh, I know there is.  I've also been doing data converts for the past 20 years and there are a /lot/ of systems that either predate the CSV or they rolled their own anyways.

Comment: @Joey: I think there's a standard for CSV the same way there's a standard for SQL.

Comment: Not quite, sorry. I'm taking a large CSV and generating a two-dimensional array of sorts, to be pasted into some JavaScript. Thanks, though.

Comment: @MichaelGruber -- In that case, make your array in Ruby then use whatever native tools you to have to dump it as `JSON`.  `JSON` is, literally, _J_ava _S_cript _O_bject  _N_otation, so you can just assign that to a Javscript variable directly.

Comment: Yeah. That would make more sense... Thanks, I'll probably give that a shot.